# Set ng-click on specific section of html page

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have this html page structure, `chart-legend` is an AngularJS component:

```
<div class="chart-legend">
    <h5 class="chart-legend-header">{{$ctrl.site}}
        <div class="chart-legend-icons">
        </div>
    </h5> 
    <p class="chart-legend-average-demand"> -- Page Title</p>
</div>
```

In another page I'm adding `ng-click` on it like this:

```
<div class="demand page">
    <div class="chart-legend-container">
        <div ng-repeat="site in $ctrl.keys">
            <chart-legend site="$ctrl.siteNames[site]" ng-click="$ctrl.updateLegendChart($ctrl.siteNames[site])" keys= "$ctrl.keys"></chart-legend>
        </div>
    <div>
</div>
```

The `ng-click` is triggered if I click anywhere inside `chart-legend`. What I want is to be triggered only when the click is performed inside `<p></p>`, on **Page Title** more exactly.

I tried to add it there like this:

```
<div class="chart-legend">
    <h5 class="chart-legend-header">{{$ctrl.site}}
        <div class="chart-legend-icons">
        </div>
    </h5> 
     <p class="chart-legend-average-demand" ng-click="$ctrl.updateLegendChart($ctrl.siteNames[site])"> -- Page Title</p>
</div>
```

It doesn't work, probably because it doesn't know who is `$sctrl`. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you create a service that implements `updateLegendChart`?

Comment: You can try passing `updateLegendChart` as a callback using component bindings.